# How to access TYPO3 action via browser

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I am building an TYPO3 extension with Extbase and want to store data which I get via HTTP GET.
Now I struggle with  possibility to use a browser to access the action controller.

The plugin is implemented into page 102
The extension key is xyzlist
the Plugin Name is xyzlistdb
The controller name is PlaylistController
The action is getAction
The domain name is sub.domain.de

In the PlaylistController.php is under getAction only 
error_log("GetAction",0);
to figure out, if the browser url goes to the getAction.

Here the URL I am using

> http://sub.domain.de/index.php?id=102&tx_xyzlist_xyzlistdb[controller]=playlist&tx_xyzlist_xyzlisdb[action]=get

In the browser I am using '&' instead of only '&'
But if I only use '&', it also not access the Get action

But I don't get any message in the log file!

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The question how to access the action controller from an external program to simulate HTTP GET. In the mean time I found out, that I have to care to use the correct notation. It is case sensetiv. For example instead of playlist I have to write Playlist. Now I can access controller, but still have problems to acces the right action. It goes always to the first action, but not to the defined one.

Comment: Please mention your TYPO3 version

Answer (score 1):

Here you have multiple possibilities...

First, you can disable `[FE][pageNotFoundOnCHashError]` (Install-Tool), so you dont get an 404 on invalid cHash. This is globaly for you site for all plugins. Its not the secure way.

Second, you can set `plugin.tx_xyzlist_xyzlistdb.features.requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 0` in your typoscript to disable the `pageNotFoundOnCHashError` for you plugin.

Last, you can add your variables to `[FE][cHashExcludedParameters]` (Install-Tool), so that your variables are not included in the cHash calculation.

Comment: @HGA I suggest the cHashExcludedParameters - setting

Comment: I tried both without success. Finally I gave up using HTTP GET and swiched to POPST.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct link, you will have to use typolink. Probably the easiest way to generate a link to a plugin action is to use `f:uri.action` in a template like this:

`<f:uri.action pageUid="102" extensionName="xyzlist" pluginName="xyzlistdb" action="get" />`

https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/Action.html

Comment: The question is how to access the action from a external program.

Comment: Create the URL once with the TYPO3 means, it will work as a usual URL then. It will append a &cHash parameter which is essential.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. With this approach I can access the action I want. But if I try to send my parameters it will not working. I think the the parameters must be send before the cHash. I need a solution without cHash, because the HTTP GET will be send from another program and I can only implement a static cHash. Do you have a solution for my problem?

Comment: I tried to disable " requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments = 0" in the setup.typoscript and also reinstalled the extension, but Typo3 still wants a cHash, which I can't provide.

Comment: why dont you first create a link inside the TYPO3 system and then copy the rendered link? If you wanna remove the cHash, then use realUrl if TYPO3 <8 or the sites Module if TYPO3 > 9. This way you will have a unique url for every call. I suppose you have UIDS so include them on the url as well

Comment: @HGA it was unclear to me from your initial question what you really want. I'll add a new answer.

Comment: Jonas, I finally gave up to use HTTP Get and switched to POST. I created inside Typo3 a link to the action with a cHash and use this link for the external program. POST gives me the possibility to use a fix call with cHash and additional gives me the possibility to be flexible with the parameters without influence the cHash. Thaks for you help, especially with the cHash. I did not know it!

Answer (score 0):

Write first letter of your controller name capitalized.

```
http://sub.domain.de/index.php?id=102&tx_xyzlist_xyzlistdb[controller]=Playlist&tx_xyzlist_xyzlisdb[action]=get
```

Also do not turn off cHash without a good reason. That problem is not a reason at all.

Jonas mentioned to generate a link to your action with:

```
<f:uri.action pageUid="102" extensionName="xyzlist" pluginName="xyzlistdb" action="get" />
```

It is indeed a good and time saving practice.